# Jquery to PHP array transfer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

Ok, I know there were many of those but my code just won't work... I tried solutions found on Stack but still...

I would like to transfer my array built in jQuery to my php script that will compare it with other array etc.

My jQuery code looks like this:

```
$.post('rezultat.php',{wyb: JSON.stringify(wybrane)});
```

and in my rezultat.php file I try to decode it:

```
$wyb = json_decode($_POST['wybrane']);
```

I tried the $_POST method before, with no results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$_POST['wyb']`, since that's what you're calling the field in the JS code. `var_dump($_POST)` will confirm that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `$_POST['wyb']` instead of `$_POST['wybrane']` in your php script, since you used `'wyb'` key in the array you created in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the parameter with his Javascript name, try to call with the `$_POST` name:

```
$wyb = json_decode($_POST['wyb']);
```

Comment: Why was this voted down when it's essentially the same as the answer above?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that already. On my page I receive this: Notice: Undefined index: wyb in C:\xampp\htdocs\rezultat.php on line 3   where line 3 is of course $wyb = json_decode($_POST['wyb']);

Comment: Check your param before send, console.log(JSON.stringify(wybrane)); and var_dump($_POST) in the other side and check your values.

Comment: Does it matter that wybrane array is empty at first? User will fill it with his own values and finally hit the button in jQuery that will start the function that sends it to php file. So technically, when I load the site, this array is empty, right?

Comment: You mean sth like this: if(isset($_POST['wyb'])){ 
$wyb = json_decode($_POST['wyb']); 
foreach($wyb as $w) {
echo $w; 
}} ? Cause it doesn't work. Sorry if I'm retarded :)